Is it true that Israel and the US have always opposed a two-state solution based on the pre-June 1967 border in recent decades?
Noam Chomsky, a Jew himself, has claimed frequently (for instance, in this 2006 TV interview that in the recent decades even Hamas has accepted a two-state solution based on international borders ("the pre-June 1967 border, with minor and mutual modifications"), and almost all the world has accepted it, with a few exceptions, including Israel and the US. He claims that many people may think Hamas is the problem and not the Israel, because the western powers have the most influential media. I personally have much respect for Chomsky, but it's always good to have an open mind. So my question is: Is it true that Israel and the US have always opposed a two-state solution for the Palestine-Israel conflict in recent decades? Please support your answer with facts and references, if possible.

There are many similar questions here about attitudes to a two-state solution: have you searched and read them? Also, how many decades? The Oslo Accords were in the mid-90s so does that count?

What does Noam Chomsky's religion have to do with his thoughts on a 2 state solution?

@DogBoy37, For many people, perhaps most people, it's difficult to criticize their own nation, group, culture, etc. Chomsky is not a religious person, but is an American Jew anyway. The fact that he places morality and truth above everything is admirable, even if he is wrong in some cases.

Did you need to channel so much Chomsky to ask this question?  Left mostly at the title, "is it true that...?", this question might have been better received.  It might have been a dupe, but I am not so sure we've seen this particular angle asked about before.  Of course, an "Is it true?" questions asking about regular (non-Hamas) Palestinian leadership obstructionism might be warranted.  For the present Hamas-based leadership, I'd say 10/7 answers such a question very well.  No DV, no UPV, just maybe try to formulate questions more neutrally, eh?

@apadana - If Chomsky is an American Jew, than Israel isn't precisely his own nation or group. Of course, Israel does have significance for some American Jews (and some American Christians!), but no one would be particularly surprised to see an American Christian criticizing the government of Nicaragua or an American Muslim criticizing that of Egypt. American Jews are not particularly unique in that regard. Chomsky's criticism of American policy might be a much better example of the point you are trying to make.

As for the rest, that just plays into the right-wing Israeli narrative that American Jews owe the Israeli government some degree of deference, and the anti-Semitic narrative that they in fact are loyal to it. I have talked to a lot of American Jews (and Americans of many other religions), and particularly among the non-religious ones, it's not at all uncommon for them to feel little affinity for Israel, and criticism is quite common.

As for AIPAC, regardless of whether one sees it as the chicken or the egg—is American policy pro-Israeli-government because AIPAC is influential, or is AIPAC influential because so many Americans were pro-Israeli-government to begin with?—it is not determinative of the opinions of American Jews. It's a small minority of a small minority. Plenty of American Jews diverge from their perspective, such as the majority who believe the Israeli government does not pursue peace.

@Obie2.0, I didn't say that Chomsky is the only American Jew who strongly criticizes the policies of Israel and the US on moral and human right grounds. But we all know it's hard to find people like him. For example, If most Americans thought like him that the sanctions against Iran is a crime, they didn't exist. The US has a democracy. In general people are selfish. They don't care if Palestinians are suffering. But it's important for them that their sons shouldn't be killed as soldiers.

An early version of the wikipage on the two-state solution describes the U.S. position like that:

Security Council resolutions dating back to June 1976 supporting the two-state solution based on the pre-1967 lines were vetoed by the United States,[14] which supports a two-state solution but argued that the borders must be negotiated directly by the parties. The idea has had overwhelming support in the UN General Assembly since the mid-1970s.[15]

So the U.S. supports a two-state solution, but only if the 2 parties agree, which they don't so practically they veto a two-state approach. Now whether it would be a solution without agreement is another question.
Apparently, the first serious moves were made in the 1970s, since in 1988 the PLO made statements that could be read as accepting the existence of Israel and the Olso Accords seem to have been promising.

At the Annapolis Conference in November 2007, three major parties—The PLO, Israel, and the US—agreed on a two-state solution as the outline for negotiations. However, the summit failed to achieve an agreement.

Also around that time public support in both camps or a two-state solution was apparently quite high.
Now as said PLO (Fatah) seems to have been in favor of that, but Hamas (current government in Gaza) was not. The closest it got was changing its charter in 2017 accepting a Palestinian state in the borders of 1967 (previously they wanted the whole of Mandatory Palestine) though no word of accepting the existence of Israel, so to count that as support or as a solution might also be shady.
While apparently the Likud party of ruling prime minister Netanyahu apparently founded themselves as hardliners rejecting any Palestinian states (though again were also closer to that in the pre-Netanyahu era) and have in recent years moved ever further to the right and with support for settlers in occupied territory and the open rejection of a two-state solution have positioned themselves so far against that that even the U.S. complained.
So yes to an extent the U.S. vetoing all sorts of proposals unless there is mutual agreement has enabled a position that keeps the status quo because little is being done and can be leveraged by for example Israel to block that concept.
But you could also argue that forcing a solution from the outside has created this mess to begin with and without general acceptance is unlikely to result in lasting peace.
And while Netanyahu openly rejects the idea and thus in recent years actually blocks any approach in that direction. There has apparently been support for that even in Israel at one point.
Also, Hamas still is a terror organization and without the acceptance of the existence of the state of Israel, that's also not a two-state solution either.
Also with regard to the U.S., every administration might change its position on that matter. Like previously the PLO had a diplomatic mission in the U.S. but under Trump that changed as well accepting Jerusalem as the capital of Israel, which apparently is a much disputed question of the status of that city.
So, I'm not sure it's fair to draw a consistent narrative here either.

"Curiously omitted from this debate is the PLO’s striking decision to support a January 1976 draft United Nations [UN] Security Council resolution explicitly calling for a two-state settlement along June 1967 borders, an initiative ultimately killed by an American veto." (https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/full/10.1080/09592296.2022.2062127)

Chomsky tells a carefully crafted narrative that omits some key things.
The 2000 Camp David talks
In the year 2000, Bill Clinton had Ehud Olmert (Israeli PM) and Yassir Arafat (PLO leader) over to Camp David to hammer out a peace deal. There were various disagreements, but Arafat basically walked away according to Bill Clinton

He described Arafat as an aging leader who relishes his own sense of victimhood and seems incapable of making a final peace deal. "He could only get to step five, and he needed to get to step 10," the former president said. But Clinton expressed hope in the younger generation of Palestinian officials, suggesting that a post-Arafat Palestinian leader might be able to make peace, perhaps in as little as several years. "I'm just sorry I blew this Middle East" thing, Clinton said shortly before leaving. "But I don't know what else I could have done."

2001 saw the Second Intifada (intense violence) and the election of Ariel Sharon, a far more conservative Israeli leader. Since that time, there has been far more skepticism in Israel that a two-state solution is possible. Something that helped to drive that further was the Israeli withdrawal from Gaza, a move that was supposed to help drive peace, but had no net effect. Hamas would win the elections in Gaza the very next year.
The Hamas charter says this (Article Six, emphasis mine)

The Islamic Resistance Movement is a distinguished Palestinian movement, whose allegiance is to Allah, and whose way of life is Islam. It strives to raise the banner of Allah over every inch of Palestine, for under the wing of Islam followers of all religions can coexist in security and safety where their lives, possessions and rights are concerned. In the absence of Islam, strife will be rife, oppression spreads, evil prevails and schisms and wars will break out.

And Article Thirteen

There is no solution for the Palestinian question except through Jihad. Initiatives, proposals and international conferences are all a waste of time and vain endeavors.

In light of October 7, 2023, this certainly seems to be the case. Hamas expressed no interest in anything but murder and taking hostages. It's not hard to see why Israel would be skeptical of such a group running a state bordering their own.

Thanks. Have you seen the debate between Alan Dershowitz and Chomsky? It's a fiery debate. One of the things they disagree on is why the 2000 Camp David talks failed. Dershowitz quotes what he has heard from Clinton, but Chomsky argues that it's invalid.

Well, TBF the Chomsky in that interview looks 5-10 years younger than he is now. Back then even Netanyahu thought that Hamas could be reasoned with, at least to some extent. And anyhow, found it preferable because it derailed the 2-state solution. https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/56315/did-netanyahu-express-support-of-hamas-in-2019

It has been long settled (this article is from 2011) that it was Israel - and particularly Netanyahu - who derailed the Oslo accords. Netanhayu has even publicly boasted about it in later years. Clinton was just lying there.

In the 2006 clip from the Q, Chomsky claims that the US (and Israel) was "unwilling to consider" (then) a two-state solution along the pre-1967 border. And he goes on to attack GW Bush a few times. He doesn't explicitly claim that the US was always unwilling to consider it, although that's one possible interpretation. In fact Wikipedia will tell you that the US position has been e.g. during Obama's time that that should be the border. But the interview was taken during GW Bush's time. So, it's probably best to consider what GW Bush policies were for the veracity of the statement.
I think Bush was generally committed to the 1967 borders, but not entirely, e.g.

Speaking after a meeting with the Palestinian president, Mahmoud Abbas, Bush said: "There should be an end to the occupation that began in 1967. An agreement must establish Palestine as a homeland for the Palestinian people, just as Israel is a homeland for the Jewish people."
[...] Bush highlighted the status of Jerusalem as perhaps the most intractable problem. "I fully understand finding a solution to this issue will be one of the most difficult challenges on the road to peace but that is the road we have chosen to walk."

Jerusalem had been divided in the "pre-1967 border".
Likewise, the Oslo Accords themselves didn't resolve the issue of Jerusalem, but it was left for future negotiations.
Wikipedia adds that

Positions on the final status of Jerusalem have varied with different Israeli governments. The Oslo Accords declared that the final status of Jerusalem would be negotiated, but Israeli Prime Minister Yitzhak Rabin declared that he would never divide the city. In 1995, he allegedly told a group of school children that "if they told us peace is the price of giving up a united Jerusalem under Israeli sovereignty, my reply would be 'let's do without peace'". This position was upheld by his successor, Benjamin Netanyahu, who stated there would be "...No withdrawal or even discussion of the case of Jerusalem...".

Netanyahu made (p. 94) that statement in May 1996 during the election campaign that he eventually won.
Wikipedia also adds:

Prime minister during the second intifada, Ariel Sharon was unequivocal in his support for an undivided Jerusalem. In an interview done one week before a stroke incapacitated him he stated: "Our position is that Jerusalem is not negotiable. We are not going to negotiate on Jerusalem. Jerusalem will be forever a united and undivided capital of Israel." Prime Minister (and former Jerusalem mayor) Ehud Olmert vowed to keep Jerusalem the "undivided, eternal capital of the Jewish people", but later supported the detachment of several Arab neighborhoods from Israeli sovereignty and the introduction of an international trust to run the Temple Mount.

Olmert had just become PM in 2006, and Wikipedia doesn't alas have a date for his change in position, but cites a 2011 interview with him, in which he does say that he was willing to consider "a Palestinian capital in Jerusalem" during the December 2006 - September 2008 negotiations, but it's somewhat unclear when this fact was first publicized so if e.g. Chomsky could have been aware of it in June 2006.
Then Netanyahu became PM again in 2009 (till 2021).
So, Chomsky was (probably) technically correct (at the time he made that statement) albeit one might say the statement is misleading to some degree, i.e. how much of the pre-1967 border was Israel's government of then (and that of the US) willing to consider.
IDK if Chomsky has repeated that statement since (as you say he did), but it's probably not wrong for the remainder of the Netanyahu's premierships that Israel wasn't willing to compromise on dividing Jerusalem. E.g. he repeated that stance in 2016.

No. Chomsky's claim are so not true it is mind boggling anyone would even try to make them.
Even Netanyahu supports a two state solution as a part of a negotiated peace treaty with security guarantees.
https://ecf.org.il/issues/issue/70
Israel made many peace offers to the Palestinians that would have allowed for a Palestinian state. Most prominent and the last one was made by Israeli PM Ehud Barack to Yasser Arafat.  Barak offered to form a Palestinian state initially on 73% of the West Bank  and 100% of the Gaza Strip. In 10–25 years, the Palestinian state would expand to a maximum of 92% of the West Bank (91 percent of the West Bank and 1 percent from a land swap.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2000_Camp_David_Summit#:~:text=Based%20on%20the%20Israeli%20definition,100%25%20of%20the%20Gaza%20Strip.
It was rejected by Arafat without even bothering to make a counteroffer. And Arafat was  a moderate by Palestinian standards. This was after he  won the  noble peace prize for his willingness to "compromise" and make peace with Israel.

a demilitarised state can hardly be called sovereign, so the situation discussed in that link is not meaningfully a two-state solution

Germany was not a sovereign state after the world wars? What about these countries? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_sovereign_states_without_armed_forces

@Tristan - On the contrary, there's nothing wrong with not having an army, and some would argue that the world would even be better off without them. It would just have had to be reciprocal to be fair. I wonder whether Israel would have been willing to dissolve its military and beat its guns into ploughshares?

The question describes Chomsky's claim thusly: "Hamas has accepted a two-state solution based on international borders". According to the linked article, that is exactly what Yasser Arafat requested at the Camp David Summit (a Palestinian state within the internationally-recognised Green Line borders), and Israel refused to offer it. I realise that the question asks whether Israel has opposed a two-state solution in general, but to categorise Chomsky's claim specifically as "mind-bogglingly false" when it's corroborated by your own source feels like a distortion of the facts.

A state not having a military is different from it being demilitarised. The latter implies some other entity preventing it from having a military, rather than it not having a military due to self-determination The fact such another entity exists is evidence of that state's lack of sovereignty

Hamas has never accepted a two-state SOLUTION based on international borders. They said  they would accept 1967 borders without recognizing state of Israel, They made it clear they will continue to fight afterwards https://www.aljazeera.com/news/2017/5/2/hamas-accepts-palestinian-state-with-1967-borders Claiming they committed to  the two state solution is mind-bogglingly false

@Tristan  Yet, yet, it is hard to reconcile the idea of an armed Palestinian state with any notion of safety for Israel.  Not after 10/7.  And Israel ultimately has to participate in accepting a 2 state solution, even if they are pushed to do so.  So maybe let's just get off our high horses, eh?  A prosperous Palestine, freed of Israeli border controls, but also with a powerful external, non-Israeli/non-UN entity keeping their hotheads under control would achieve a lot more than insisting on rainbows and unicorns.

@ItalianPhilosopher and it is just as hard to reconcile the idea of an armed Israeli state with an notion of safety for Palestine since 1948. A two-state solution where one state is demilitarised is just an internationally recognised bantustan. A two-state solution with both demilitarised would have dubious sovereignty for both states, but would at least be equitable

@Tristan It's not a question of equitable or not.  It is a question of realism.  The status quo - 10/7 aside - suits the Israeli government and a significant chunk of its population just fine.  They have military dominance and are bit by bit annexing the West Bank (which then gets talked up as "facts on the ground").  Given their Western backers, they have no reason to compromise, at this point.  Those backers may yet lose patience or influence, but the best way to keep them supporting Israel is to use exactly your kind of proposal.  Which is pure strawman.

What Israel needs to cut a deal is both external pressure - being a democracy does not give you a right to oppress other nations/groups, even if it is an internal democratic mandate.  And sufficient security assurances to make it more palatable to downgrade their security posture.  But, again given 10/7, it is equally clear that the Israelis, who hold most of the cards right now, have reason to be cautious.  A militarized Gaza is just not to be trusted.  Whether a militarized Israel is to be trusted is irrelevant to Israel changing its own position.

@ItalianPhilosopher true, the fact a two-state "solution" with only Israel armed isn't equitable is the least of the issues with it. As you point out, under such a system Israel would be just as able to continue its piecemeal annexation of the West Bank which they already have piecemeal control over. That is my point. There is little practical difference between such a "solution" and the (pre 7th of October) status quo, and so calling it a two-state solution is disingenuous
